# What largest websites are written in php?

Tags: php, web-development

What are some of the largest and most popular websites in the world written in php? I know 1 - this is `wikipedia`, tell please another large website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the graph on this site which displays some of the worlds largest websites and shows what they are built on

http://royal.pingdom.com/2007/08/22/what-nine-of-the-world%E2%80%99s-largest-websites-are-running-on/

And one other list which is pretty similar

http://blog.richardknop.com/2010/03/some-really-large-php-websites/

Comment: Take a look at facebook

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is written in PHP too :)